# Verbs for powdered milk, hot chocolate powder, and tea?

Tags: word-choice

What are the verbs for mixing milk with hot water, chocolate powder with hot water, or tea with hot water?
Such as:

> I am preparing my powdered milk?
>   I am making my hot chocolate?
>   I am pouring hot water with my tea?

It has bothered me for a long time. However, it is a typical question, which can not be solved by dictionaries.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you edit your question to make is clearer? The subject conflicts with the body, and each of the sentences seem to conflict with each other.

Comment: Just FTR you're allowed to use a capital letter to begin the sentence which is your question title. There's no extra charge. You can use the edit button to fix this problem.

Comment: Just as Andy says.  If you're having trouble finding the edit button (many people seem to - it should be larger) it is just below the last sentence of your question body.

Comment: Joe Blow: Thank for your comment. It is done.
andy256: Do you have any suggestion about how to rewrite the question? Thank you.

Comment: I'll make an edit. You can roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: "*Making* hot drinks".

Answer (score 4):

The word is *make*.

> I will make the milk. I will make the hot chocolate. I will make the tea.

See, for example [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=make).

Answer (score 3):

With SWR, often the answer is "there is no such single word."

Traditionally someone officially gives that as an answer, so:

There **is no single word** for "adding liquid to...".  You just have to say "adding liquid to..."

Moving one step up conceptually and using 'making" is the best you can do here.  If you're literally writing an explanation of how to make these drinks (a recipe, receipt, as it were) you would have to use "add water to" for that step - as you can see in recipe books.

In arcane situations (like, a science lab when adding small amounts of liquid in to some powder) you can use **"wetting"**.

Please note that when the answer to a SWR is *"is no single word** for..."* then, logically, it's impossible to "give a reference" for that, since you can't prove a negative. (Except in the bizarre case that there's a research paper on the existence of such a term.)

Answer (score 2):

For making tea, you could say **steeping** or **brewing**.
For mixing powders such as powdered milk or cocoa powder with liquid, you'd use a more general purpose word like **making** or **mixing**.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I say that I steep a cup of tea or I steep a tea bag?

Comment: I would say "I'm brewing a cup of tea." If I were explaining why I hadn't drunk my tea yet, I would say "I'm letting my tea steep."

Answer (score 2):

You could go with **make**.

As in: "I am **making** a glass of milk. I am **making** a glass of hot chocolate. I am **making** tea."

Would it sound awkward if we use **fix**? as in " I will **fix** up a glass of milk".

Comment: For the milk I would use *making up* powdered milk. Probably because you don't normally make milk from ingredients unlike the other 2 examples.

Answer (score 1):

Although *rehydrate* has its root in [water](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hydro-), a definition allowing for any liquid may be found in [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rehydrate):

> to restore moisture or fluid to (something dehydrated).

Similarly, *rehydrate* is given as a definition for [*hydrate*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hydrate).

*Rehydrate* then seems particularly suitable for powdered milk, which is a once-wet product that has been [evaporated to dryness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powdered_milk). It may not fit as well with products that have not been dehydrated, though.

Comment: side note: Another word for rehydrating something to its original consistency or strength is "reconstitute".  I wouldn't use this in ordinary conversation, but you might see it on a label, particularly of fruit juice "made from concentrate", where the first ingredient is usually "water sufficient to reconstitute".